# Assembler explain line

Tags: assembly, tasm

can someone explain what means this line, or provide with source where it is described:

```
bufor times 400h DB 0
```

i know that "bufor" it is name. What is "times" and for what are used for?

It is not the same as stack segment, or it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"times" is a macro that repeats command. Your line means "Point Bufor to array of 400h (or 1024) zero bytes".
Here is the example: http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html at 3.2.5 section

Comment: Correct for Nasm... but I don't think it'll work for Tasm(?). Look into `DUP`.